# OSError: access violation reading 0xXXXXXXXXXXX error when calling a DLL using ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, access-violation

I've searched for answers to this question but I keep turning up empty. I've managed to get a couple of the DLL's working but this one is giving me some trouble:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import my_module

dll = CDLL('C:\\Path_to_dll')
MF = (b'C:\\Path_to_file')
```

this does not work:

```
PN = (b'parameter_name')
beginTime = ctypes.c_double(-value)
endTime = ctypes.c_double(+value)
DT_RETURNGMT = 0x0100
DT_FLOAT = 0x0001
convertType = (DT_RETURN|DT_BOOL)
Null = 0

dll.readPam.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p, 
c_double, c_double, c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,
dll.readPam.restype = POINTER(Pam)
```

This is where the error shows up:

```
g = dll.readPam(f, PN, beginTime, endTime, Null, Null, convertType)

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

My question is this: What exacting is the error indicating it can't read and how can I fix it?
What the dll should do is print out data values when I type:

```
print(g)
print(g[0].tS[0].data)
dll.freePam(g)
```

Comment: You need to show an [mcve] that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just from the syntax highlight alone one can see that there are syntax mistakes in your code....!

Comment: @RossRidge I've added more information on my code

Comment: @TomdeGeus I've edited my mistakes and added more information. Do you still see syntax mistakes?

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my mistakes are the negative votes still necessary now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. I was freeing my file before I was done using it. So where I wrote:

```
dll.freeFile(f)
```

I was freeing the file when I shouldn't have.  So I removed that line and now it's at the end of my code. Ironically enough once I solved this problem python gave me another one...